# Unable to get complete git history of file with python

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am trying to get all the content from each revision - history of a file in my local repo i am using gitpython lib and here is the code:

```
import git,json
from pprint import pprint
repo = git.Repo()
path = "my_file_path"

revlist = (
    (commit, (commit.tree / path).data_stream.read())
    for commit in repo.iter_commits(paths=path)
)

for commit, filecontents in revlist:
    filecontentsjs = json.loads(filecontents)
    pprint(commit)
    pprint(filecontentsjs["execution_status"])
    pprint(filecontentsjs["execution_end_time"])
```

Problem: i am comparing our bitbucket history and the history i get from this script and the script comes up short, meaning the bitbucket history has more revisions of the file but when i clone the repo locally i get like half of the revisions with the script

am i missing something here? limitation or anything like that?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? Or an example of the difference ? Just guessing : maybe it has to do with merge commits ?

Comment: Well we use bitbucket so i go to my repo and to a file and click history so i see around 7-8 commits with different authors different dates for a specific file, and then i clone that repo to my local machine and i run "git log -- file_path --pretty=online" or "git rev-list HEAD --online file_name" and i get only 4 commits for the same file

Comment: For command-line Git, add `--full-history`. As for what to do here for GitPython, you'll have to look in the documentation to find the equivalent. Note that there's no such thing as "file history" in Git: what you're getting is *filtered commit history*, and the rules for the filtering determine which commit(s) you get. Adding `--full-history` simply changes the filtering rules. Bitbucket use their own filtering which is not easily duplicated, so you might also need to add `-m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it turns out it was my fault i didn't notice that the filename changed slightly and bitbucket did what it supposed to do since it thought "if the code is the same the file is the same" which is not true

so adding the --follow flag in the git log i was seeing the full "bad" history.
The real "good" history is without the --follow since i care only about the file with the same name